# Java: How to Scrape Images from Amazon with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to scrape the 6 images on left side of page from this URL on Amazon using Selenium WebDriver:

[http://www.amazon.com/EasyAcc%C2%AE-10000mAh-Brilliant-Smartphone-Bluetooth/dp/B00H9BEC8E](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H9BEC8E)

However, whatever I try causes an error. What I've tried so far:

1. I tried scraping images directly using XPATH and then extracting src using "getAttributes" method. For example, for the 1st image on page the XPATH is:

   .//*[@id='a-autoid-2']/span/input

so I tried the following:

```
  String path1 = ".//*[@id='a-autoid-2']/span/input";
        String url = "http://www.amazon.com/EasyAcc%C2%AE-10000mAh-Brilliant-Smartphone-Bluetooth/dp/B00H9BEC8E";
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url);
  WebElement s;
        s = driver.findElement(By.xpath(path1));
        String src;
        src = s.getAttribute("src");
        System.out.println(src);
```

But I'm unable to find source.

Note: This problem occurs only when scraping images from certain types of products. For example, I can easily scrape images from this product using Selenium:

[http://www.amazon.com/Ultimate-Unification-Diet-Health-Disease/dp/0615797806/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0615797806)

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class mytest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        String path = ".//*[@id='imgThumbs']/div[2]/img";

        String url = "http://www.amazon.com/Ultimate-Unification-Diet-Health-Disease/dp/0615797806/";
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url);


        WebElement s;
        s = driver.findElement(By.xpath(path));
        String src;
        src = s.getAttribute("src");
        System.out.println(src);

        driver.close();


    }
}
```

This code works flawlessly. It is only when scraping certain products that there seems to be no way around it.

2. I tried clicking on image which causes an iframe to open but I'm unable to scrape images from this iframe either, even after switching to iframe with:

   driver.switchTo().frame(IFRAMEID);

I know I can use the "screenshot" method but I'm wondering if there's a way to scrape the images directly?

Thanks

Comment: I think XPath is little complicated. Why not use CSS path?

Comment: I actually tried CSS too but it did not work. The solution listed below works. However, I'm trying to figure out why Firebug did not display this XPATH when I hovered over image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    String path = "//div[@id='imageBlock_feature_div']//span/img";

    String url = "http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615797806";
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(url);

    List<WebElement> srcs;
    srcs = driver.findElements(By.xpath(path));

    for(WebElement src : srcs) {
        System.out.println(src.getAttribute("src"));
    }

    driver.close();
```

Result

```
2015-01-23 12:36:14 [main]-[INFO] Opened url: http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H9BEC8E
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41cOP3mFX3L._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51YkMhRXqcL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51nSbXF%2BCTL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31s%2B31F%2BQmL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41FmTOJEOOL._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41U6qpLJ07L._SX38_SY50_CR,0,0,38,50_.jpg
```

However, to get Amazon Images, I suggest you to try Amazon API https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

It's much better.

Comment: your solution worked flawlessly. So I guess my problem was I was using the wrong XPATH? I could not find the XPATH in your answer using Firebug.. Is this custom made?